# WorldPay TemplateForm throwing error when other Javascript is present in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, worldpay

I'm using **WorldPay TemplateForm** in a aspx page. I've done this simply by pasting all the Javascript code, as per the [documentation](https://online.worldpay.com/docs/templateform-advanced-usage), i.e:

```
  Worldpay.useTemplateForm({
  ... 
  }
```

This code generates a form where the user types in their credit card info.

That works fine.

The problem I'm having is that if I try to add a `span`  which contains a countdown timer (to let the user know when their time is up to make the payment) then I get the following error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
>   For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

One way to solve this is by removing my `span` altogether.

The other solution I've found is by adding the following directives to my .aspx Page:

```
 ValidateRequest="false" EnableEventValidation="false"
```

I've read that **it is not safe to set these directives to false** in a .aspx page. Yet I haven't found  any other way to keep my JScript timer in the same page as the one with the WorldPay form.

My Javascript countdown timer is made up only of a `setTimeout` and a `setInterval`.

**Does anyone know if there are any special restrictions for having additional Javascript to the one of the WorldPay form?**

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.